# Why is the maximum sum of two proportions = 1 with the multinomial logit

Tags: limits, multinomial-coefficients

Suppose I have two numbers, actually two proportions, `a` and `b`, where:

```
a = e^x / (1 + e^x + e^y)

b = e^y / (1 + e^x + e^y)
```

I know that if `x` and `y` are very small the lower limit of `a` and `b` is `0`.  I also know that if `x` and `y` are both very big `a` and `b` both approach `0.50`.

However, it seems if `a = 0.80` then the upper limit of `b = 0.20`.  More generally, `a + b <= 1` and the upper limit of `b` is `1 - a`.  Why is that?

Thank you for any advice in understanding why `a + b` must be `<= 1` and why the upper limit of `b` is `1 - a`.  Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that a + b = 1 - 1/(1+e^x + e^y) < 1

and the sum will approach 1 (equivalently, 1/(1+e^x + e^y) will approach 0)

as x and y approach infinity

Answer (score 1):

Let $c = \frac{1}{1+e^x + e^y}$, which is a positive real number.

Then $a+b+c=1$, and any positive solution of $a+b+c=1$ can be attained by some choice of $x$ and $y$.   By taking $c$ to be small one gets $b$ as close as desired to $1-a$; and certainly $a+b \leq 1$.

The exponentials $e^x$ and $e^y$ are just a way of saying "a pair of positive numbers".